# c# Decrypt data which stored in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm, encryption

In ms SQL server, I have a field text with data look like below:

```
"!"$$$$$$!#$$$$!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!! "!! ! " !" ! !" !!!! ! !!"!".
```

I belive that from a plain text string, they using a Rijndael algorithm to encrypted this string. from encrypted string, it was transform to string above.

Can anyone recognize what the algorithm to decrypt from string above to the encrypted string of Rijndael algorithm?

thanks

Comment: Are there only these 5 symbols? (", ,$,!,#)

Comment: Exactly, it has only 5 symbols

Answer (score -1):

Hi me drona please find the below code. It will useful from you.

```
public static class Encrypt
    {
        // This size of the IV (in bytes) must = (keysize / 8).  Default keysize is 256, so the IV must be
        // 32 bytes long.  Using a 16 character string here gives us 32 bytes when converted to a byte array.
        private const string initVector = "pemgail9uzpgzl88";
        // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm
        private const int keysize = 256;
        //Encrypt
        public static string EncryptString(string plainText, string passPhrase)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        }
        //Decrypt
        public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        }
```

`enter code here`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide an explanation and do not just paste code snippets as an answer.

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block on SO.